# Adaptive Card is not showing the image in web application

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I am using the dotNet sdk. All the images are stored in the wwwroot/Image folder i.e. Static folder.
When i am running the bot through emulator i.e. Locally it is showing the image.
But after publishing the application the image is not showing up.
when i debug program remotly then i am getting the proper image path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Image\pdf.jpg
, which is currect url but sill image is not showing up.

```
new AdaptiveColumn() {
    Width=AdaptiveColumnWidth.Auto,
    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
    {
        new AdaptiveImage()
        {
            //Url = new Uri(iconUrl),
            Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Small,
            Style = AdaptiveImageStyle.Default,
            UrlString=iconUrl
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you saying you're using a local path as your image URL? If you're serving the image in wwwroot then why aren't you using the remote URL?

Comment: Also make sure, wherever you are publishing your app to, the images are actually being published aswell. Was helping someone some time ago and everything that was missing is that the images where not copied over by the publishing assistant.

Comment: @TimCadenbach i had check the published application through Kudu. and i able to see those images there with the proper path as :  D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Image\pdf.jpg

Comment: DId you try to open the images in the browser directly? is the path as you think it is? And also similar to what Kyle is saying there, you should use the full image path (best with http://etc) in the card.

Comment: @KyleDelaney when i dibug the program remotely i m getting the similar URL and this is the URL of kudu service where my application is published. It is the dynamic generated URL. Which i get from " Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
       "wwwroot", "Image", "pdf.jpg")". Is there is any algternative to get image of wwwroot folder.

Comment: @RajatNegi - Is my answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Answer (score 0):

Any location starting with a drive letter like D is a local path and not a remote URL. You should never use a local path when trying to identify resources on a server, since your bot is communicating with a client on a totally different machine.

Please familiarize yourself with this document to understand how static files work in .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Once your web app is running on a server, you will be able to access the image using HTTP/S. If you're running the bot locally then the URL should look something like http://localhost:3978/Image/pdf.jpg and if the bot is deployed then it should look something like https://rajatbot.azurewebsites.com/Image/pdf.jpg. Test the URL by pasting it into a browser to make sure it works, then put the URL in your card.